# how to find indices of k smallest numbers in a multidimentional array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to form an array containing indices of k smallest values in an array:

```
import heapq
import numpy as np

a= np.array([[1, 3, 5, 2, 3],
       [7, 6, 5, 2, 4],
       [2, 0, 5, 6, 4]])

[t[0] for t in heapq.nsmallest(2,enumerate(a[1]),lambda(t):t[1])]
===[3, 4]
```

But this fails:

```
[t[0] for t in heapq.nsmallest(2,enumerate(a.all()),lambda(t):t[1])]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    [t[0] for t in heapq.nsmallest(2,enumerate(a.all()),lambda(t):t[1])]
TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Would you care to state some assumptions about why it's failing?  This question is obtuse, as-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.ndenumerate` with a heap, or a partial sort as suggested by David:

```
a = np.array([[1, 3, 5, 2, 3],
       [7, 6, 5, 2, 4],
       [2, 0, 5, 6, 4]])
heap = [(v, k) for k,v in numpy.ndenumerate(npa)]
heapq.heapify(heap)
heapq.nsmallest(10, heap) # for k = 10
```

And you get:

```
[(0, (2, 1)),
 (1, (0, 0)),
 (2, (0, 3)),
 (2, (1, 3)),
 (2, (2, 0)),
 (3, (0, 1)),
 (3, (0, 4)),
 (4, (1, 4)),
 (4, (2, 4)),
 (5, (0, 2))]
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution, but it seems to be slower. Python stdlib is not so great at handling pure number crunching, as it allows for rich comparison for arbitrary objects.

Comment: You can probably recover the 2D indexes from the flattened array with index_tricks

Comment: For increased speed you can use a fixed-size heap that holds only as many elements as you need and insert the tuples individually. Then you don't need to take the top-k elements as that's all you have. The heap solution has the added virtue of being legible :)

Comment: Actually, building the list already takes 17 µs, the heap 5, and the `nsmallest` 16. `argsort` takes 3 µs. Recovering the 2D indices will take some time, but it will still be faster. For larger arrays, the difference remains, but `argpartition` is even faster (a factor of 133 for (500, 500)). About readability, I guess it is a matter of opinion. I find `argsort` more transparent in the how, but the what is equally simple in both.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in `a.all()`:

```
[t[0] for t in heapq.nsmallest(2,enumerate(a.all()),lambda(t):t[1])]
```

This checks the truthness of all the elements of your array, that is `False` (as you have a 0).

If the arrays are not too big compared with k, you can get the values using `.argsort`. Here I will select the positions of the two biggest for each row:

```
print a.argsort()[:,:2]

array([[0, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 0]])
```

If you want the positions of the global minima, flatten the array firts:

```
a.flatten().argsort()[:2]
```

If the arrays are very large, you can get a better performance using [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html#numpy.argpartition), that will perform only a partial sort.